# qsub: Bad Job Array Request, slot limit

Tags: pbs, qsub, torque

I am attempting to make a batch submission a to cluster with TORQUE. I want to submit an array of jobs but limit the number that can run concurrently to 5. How do you submit a job array using the slot limit?

I have tried:

> qsub job.sh -t 1-20%5

but receive the error:

> qsub: Bad Job Array Request.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Which version of torque do you have? Please note that this syntax to limit the number of available slots was not supported in earlier versions of torque, e.g. 2.x.x.

Comment: Hi Dmitri, I didn't consider this. Thank you. I suppose it is not supported.
> qsub version: 2.4.16